# The "TEXT COPY" function does not work.. Help me

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, copy

I have this code that sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't.
I am not very involved in these topics, but I need to fix it.
Can you help me solve my problem?

this code

```
function CopyToClipboard(containerid){if(document.selection)
{var range=document.body.createTextRange();range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));range.select().createTextRange();document.execCommand("copy");}
else if(window.getSelection){var range=document.createRange();range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));window.getSelection().addRange(range);
document.execCommand("copy");$("#text-3").fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut()}}
function myFunction(){var copyText=document.getElementById("myInput");copyText.select();copyText.setSelectionRange(0,99999);document.execCommand("copy");$("#text-2").fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();}
```

html

```
<button name="copy text" onclick="CopyToClipboard('div1')"></button>
<div id="div1"><h3>my text</h3><br></div>

<div id="text-2">notif 2</div>
<div id="text-3">notif 3</div>
```

I am looking for a code for this case that is up-to-date and different browsers do not have problems with this code
I will post the code here

Comment: do you want to copy to clipboard div data ?

Comment: @mayur-sancheti yes.. and showing notification after copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like below,

```js
function copyToClipboard() {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.getElementById('div1').innerText);
    //alert('data copied');
    document.getElementById('messageis').style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('messageis').style.display = "none";
  }, 3000);
  
}
```

```css
  #messageis
  {
    display: none;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;  
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left:30%;

  }
```

```html
<button name="copy text" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy</button>
<div><h3 class="rt rt-13 rt-medium" id="div1">my text</h3><br></div>
<div id="messageis">Code Copied</div>
```

Comment: thank you @mayur-sancheti . There is only one case. The notification appears by default in the browser, and I want the message to appear at the bottom of the screen and customize it to be more beautiful

Comment: now check again, i remove default alert, add own message box

Comment: I tested the code again and it works. There is only one problem. When the desired section is copied, the codes are also copied, such as <BR> <P> and...
I want it to copy only the text. can you help?

Comment: See this link. Lyrics section
https://www.faz2music.ir/sting-shape-of-my-haert/#div1

Comment: now check small mistake it's innerText not innerHTML  , try this in new webpage

Comment: I wrote a comment to thank you, but it seems to have been deleted. I don't know the reason for deleting it, but I came to write again, thank you. your work is great. Maybe these codes seem simple, but for me isn't simple.

Comment: @Faz2Music.ir  welcome, it's ok , have a nice day